# Navigation bar does not appear on all screens

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a full flutter app, and I'm implementing a bottomNavigationBar. What I would like to know is if there is a way to make the bar appear on all app screens, since, as I did, it only appears on the 4 main screens.

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: widget._colors.white,
  extendBody: true,
  body: buildPages(_index),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    selectedItemColor: widget._colors.orange,
    unselectedItemColor: widget._colors.grey,
    items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svgs/icons/icon_home.svg',
              color: _index == 0
                  ? widget._colors.orange
                  : widget._colors.grey),
          label: 'Home'),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svgs/icons/icon_contacts.svg',
              color: _index == 1
                  ? widget._colors.orange
                  : widget._colors.grey),
          label: 'Contacts'),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/svgs/icons/icon_historic.svg',
              color: _index == 2
                  ? widget._colors.orange
                  : widget._colors.grey),
          label: 'Historic'),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svgs/icons/icon_prof.svg',
              color: _index == 3
                  ? widget._colors.orange
                  : widget._colors.grey),
          label: 'Profile'),
    ],
    currentIndex: _index,
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    onTap: onTap,
  ),

   Widget buildPages(int index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return pageStart();
    }
    return _pages[index];
  }
```

Comment: please share this `buildPages(_index),`

Comment: I guess that the problem is that you're returning another scaffold in one of the views from buildPages(_index) and it 'overrides' your bottomNavigationBar, but no way to be sure without more info

Comment: @ritikkumarsrivastava I have added the method

Comment: it's still insufficient need to see all the 4 widgets